# Retrieving Data from a crashed mysql table

Tags: mysql, corrupt

I am trying to retrieve some data from a mysql table that is marked as crashed. I am working on a restored backup of a machine, so I don't need to worry about anything.

When I try to mysqldump the table (FYI I am using --where to specify which records I need), I get an error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 144: Table './[db]/[table]' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed when doing LOCK TABLES
```

If I use --lock-tables=false I get the same error (but failed when doing SHOW FIELDS).

If I try to just SELECT the first record from the table I get the same error.

If I run CHECK TABLE [table], I get the following warnings/errors:

```
warning  | 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly |
warning  | Size of indexfile is: 1991678976      Should be: 1024 |
error    | Record-count is not ok; is 30030697   Should be: 0    |
warning  | Found 141967876 deleted space.   Should be 0          |
warning  | Found 3101578 deleted blocks       Should be: 0       |
warning  | Found 34721783 key parts. Should be: 0                |
error    | Corrupt                                               |
```

This implies that if I do a repair table, I will lose all the data! There should be 30030697 records there....

Is there any way for me to get to this data?

Comment: This just looks like MyISAM index corruption. Repairing the table will rebuild the index. Before doing anything, you should make a physical backup of all your database files.

Comment: @TheVedge even though it says that it thinks the record count should be 0? I am worried that the repair will "fix" the table to have no records, but I will give it a shot (I guess it will take a while with 30m records)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repair the table in question issue the command

`myisamchk --recover /var/lib/mysql/DATABASENAME/TABLE_NAME.myi`

(Where DATABASENAME is the name of the database you are working with and TABLE_NAME is the name of the table to be checked.)

If this does not fully recover the table, you can re-run the command replacing –recover with –safe-recover which is slower and more thorough.

They only take a dump like that if there was some serious conflict during a row level lock, or bad write (bad sector).

Comment: Thanks. I was concerned that because CHECK TABLE said there should be 0 records that it would repair the table and leave me with no records, but I tried it and it worked. Note that instead of

    -recover

it should be 

    --recover

Comment: I think those numbers (0 records) referred to the content of the index, not the table itself, but the message could use a bit more clarity...